# On Google Spreadsheet, how do you call the CIty, Country of an IP?

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, geolocation

I would like to know if there is a formula/script one could use on Google Spreadsheet to obtain the City,Location of an array of IP addresses.

i.e lets imagine that each cell on column A has 100 IP addresses, what formula/script should I use on column B to get the respective city and location?

Comment: After downloading a database of IPs v.s. cities, You could use the  **VLOOKUP()**  worksheet function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some digging I've figured out how to do this.

1. Copy the `import_json_appsscript.js` script on https://gist.github.com/chrislkeller/5719258. This will be the script that will create the `ImportJSON()` function to a Google spreadsheet
2. Go to Google spreadsheet, on the menu bar got to Tools > Script Editor
3. Copy paste `import_json_appsscript.js` into the Script Editor and save it, Double check that you can see the `ImportJSON()` function on the Select function drop down menu.
4. On the Spreadsheet use function =ImportJSON(url, query, options), for example `=ImportJSON("http://freegeoip.net/json/75.148.30.137", "/city", "noHeaders")` to retrieve `Baltimore` from the FreeGeoIP call.

Hope that helps, it certainly answers my question.

Comment: I had to use https://www.iplocate.io/api/lookup/8.8.8.8 as the service above returned an error, however this still worked great!

Comment: Had to use IPStack per below answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54720051/3154056

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way to do this via an external service. [IPInfo](https://ipinfo.io/) supports requesting a single field, so you can actually do this without using any addon (via `IMPORTDATA` function). Quick example:

For country: `=IMPORTDATA("https://ipinfo.io/" & A1 & "/country")`

For city: `=IMPORTDATA("https://ipinfo.io/" & A1 & "/country")`

Here `A1` is IP address cell.

To avoid getting rate limited, you can register for a free account (50k monthly requests) and use a token.

**Disclaimer**: I work at IPInfo.

Comment: thanx, what we need to do to show something like this:

Mumbai, Maharashtra, India

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to write a macro of some sort, you could consider using freegeoip.net which lets you make a simple restful call to get back data in a variety of formats.

http://freegeoip.net/

For example, a call to find the location for the ip address 75.148.30.137
would look like this:

```
http://freegeoip.net/json/75.148.30.137
```

Also, here is a link to Google's documentation on how to make rest calls in a Google app:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I recently implemented the same scenario with [IP Stack API](https://ipstack.com/). API will return a Json response with all geolocation details.

```
for(var i in IPs)
{
  var url = 'http://api.ipstack.com/'+ IPs[i][0]+ '?access_key=access_key&output=json';
  var httpResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var rspns = httpResponse.getResponseCode();
  //deal with this response
}
```

Read full google sheet implementation from here; [Find Geo location of Multiple IP addresses via Google Apps Script](https://www.iranthajayasekara.com/blog/find-geo-location-of-multiple-IP-addresses-via-google-apps-script.html)

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
function parseIPApi() {
  var url = 'https://ipapi.co/75.148.30.137/json';
  var parse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  console.log(parse.getContentText())
}
```

Result:

```
{
    "ip": "75.148.30.137",
    "version": "IPv4",
    "city": "Woodbridge",
    "region": "Virginia",
    "region_code": "VA",
    "country": "US",
    "country_name": "United States",
    "country_code": "US",
    "country_code_iso3": "USA",
    "country_capital": "Washington",
    "country_tld": ".us",
    "continent_code": "NA",
    "in_eu": false,
    "postal": "22191",
    "latitude": 38.6326,
    "longitude": -77.2661,
    "timezone": "America/New_York",
    "utc_offset": "-0400",
    "country_calling_code": "+1",
    "currency": "USD",
    "currency_name": "Dollar",
    "languages": "en-US,es-US,haw,fr",
    "country_area": 9629091.0,
    "country_population": 327167434,
    "asn": "AS7922",
    "org": "COMCAST-7922"
}
```