# How can I find geolocation of MULTIPLE IP addresses via Google Apps Script in Google Sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a list of IP addresses in Column A of my sheet and I need to translate those IP Addresses into Country and city on the next columns. How can I do this via Google Apps script in Google sheets?

Comment: Welcome. There are many ways of doing this, though none (that I know of) natively within Google sheets. If you would like more assistance, would you please outline the research that you have already done on this?

Answer (score 0):

You want the Country and City of IP addresses in Column A.

Google Sheets does not have a 'native' function to do this, and the Google Maps Geolocation API requires a billing account (though there is a [$200 monthly credit](https://developers.google.com/maps/billing-credits#Monthly) which permits the equivalent of [40,000 geolocation requests](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet/)).

There are many examples on StackOverflow of using an external API though very few using Google Sheets. In addition, none are particularly recent, and some are out-dated because of elapse of time, and other APIs may offer "free" geolocation services but require an account to access the API.

This answer demonstrates the process using *iplocate.com* which does not require an account to access their free API.

---

```
function so5840531801() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetname = "IP_sheet";
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);

  //get the IP values
  var LR = sheet.getLastRow();
  var ipdata = sheet.getRange(1,1,LR,1).getValues();
  var iplength  = ipdata.length;
  // Logger.log(iplength);// DEBUG 

    // props to [wcndave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20456709/1330560)
    // for link to iplocate
    // iplocate have an API but dont require an account
  for (var i=0; i<iplength; i++){
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: i="+i+", IP = "+ipdata[i][0]);
    var url = "https://www.iplocate.io/api/lookup/"+ipdata[i][0];
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: url = "+url)
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    // Logger.log(response.getContentText());//DEBUG
    var jsondata = JSON.parse(response);  
    Logger.log("DEBUG: Country = "+jsondata.country+", City = "+jsondata.city);
    }
}
```